# Overlapping in label control text - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, label, progress-bar, overlap

I'm trying to show the typical information of the program state during runtime in a label control. So, this label is continuously changing. 
I set the label text in a function where I control the progress bar also:

```
Public Sub InCrementarProgressBar(ByVal addValue As Integer, ByVal code As String)
        Me.ProgressBar1.Value = Me.ProgressBar1.Value + addValue
        lblProgressBar.Text = code
        lblProgressBar.Refresh()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
End Sub
```

The problem is that the `code` sometimes is larger than others, so the new label text is overlapping the old one. And if the older label text is larger than the newer, the text fraction that is not covered by the newer is still visible, and I don't want it. This is an example how it looks when it occurs:
[image]

The current label text is `Reading secondary species...` and the previous text was `Reading thermodynamic parameters...`.

I tried to do something like `lblProgressBar.Text = "                        "` before assigning the code string to text label, but that is inelegant and it didn't work either.

Comment: You could try putting a Me.Refresh in but that might cause some flicker. You should really be updating your progress bar and label in a separate thread

Comment: But, what I win doing it separately? Both are independent objects but they are related, that's the reason why I'm doing it in the same thread.

Comment: Thank you @MattWilko. Your solution worked fine. I put `Me.Refresh()` instead of `lblProgressBar.Refresh()`. Why is this working fine now and it did not work fine before?

Comment: Because the label's AutoSize property is True.  Which makes it shrink when the Text string isn't as wide.  Which requires the form to draw its background to over-paint the previous pixels.  Which isn't happening when you hang your UI.  The next problem you will run into is when this work takes more than 5 seconds.  You'll get the "Not Responding" ghost window and neither the progress bar nor the label will update anymore.  Didn't we already tell you about BackgroundWorker before?

Comment: Yes, people told me about BackgroundWorker but I'm not good at vb.net and I don't know anything about BackgroundWorker. I have to study in order to understand how it works and implement this in my code for the progress bar...

Comment: Some time ago I wrote an article on BackgroundWorker. It might be useful for you. It can be found here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?680130-Correct-way-to-use-the-BackgroundWorker

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the Form's `DoubleBuffered` property to True. This should most likely solve such problems.

Comment: OK.. Then set the `AutoSize` property of the Label to False, and stretch it to fit max display area. Since you are already calling the Label.Refresh method, it will invalidate and redraw that area.

Comment: Anyhow I fix it with  the @MattWilko solution. Thank you anyway!